At what point do I transform binomial predicitions on logit scale back to the response scale?
I am working with nest success data. Nests are either successful (1) or not (0), depending on whether or not a nest produces at least 1 hatchling. Because this is binomial data, I am running glmmer models (fixed effect = age, random intercept = bird ID) with family=binomial (link="logit"). I am interested in the fixed effect predictions.
Of course, I would like to "backtransform" the model predictions from the logit scale to the "response" scale.
When using scale="response" in de predict() function, I noticed that the predictions were always way too low, so I wondered whether this had something to do with predict function. That is why I started trying to "manually" predict the model fit results. I basically just do what the predict() function does, creating a prediction matrix with values based on the model coefficients, accounting for the random intercept by sampling from a normal distribution with mu=0 and sd=sqrt(random intercept variance). I take the mean of the matrix columns to get my desired fixed effect estimates on the logit scale.
When transforming those values by exp(estimate)/1+exp(estimate) I get the same values as with predict(scale="response"). So yay, my code works, but my predictions are still way too low. If I perform the "transformation" on the individual matrix elements rather than on their column mean, my predictions turn out way too high.
Is there a rule on when/where one should perform the transformation? It matters a lot for the outcome on the response scale...
Below is an example of my code. My model structure is as follows:
y~age+I(age^2)+I(age^3)+(1|ID), hence the 3 different slopes. example2 transforms the predictions to the response scale at the end (similar to predict(scale="response"). example transforms individual matrix elements before taking the column mean. I put my model coefficients in the code to provide you with an example.
The ggplot shows the difference between the two methods.
example<-function(int, slope, slope2, slope3, var_random_intercept,maxage,minage,replicates){
  age<-seq(minage,maxage,1)
  y<-array(data=NA, dim=c(replicates, length(age))) 
  for( i in 1:replicates) {
    y[i,]<-exp(int+
                 rnorm(1,0, sqrt(var_random_intercept))+
                 slope*age+
                 slope2*(age^2)+
                 slope3*(age^3))/(1+exp(
                   int+
                     rnorm(1,0, sqrt(var_random_intercept))+
                     slope*age+
                     slope2*(age^2)+
                     slope3*(age^3)
                 ))}
  return(colMeans(y))}

example2<-function(int, slope, slope2,slope3, var_random_intercept,maxage,minage,replicates){
  age<-seq(minage,maxage,1)
  y<-array(data=NA, dim=c(replicates, length(age))) 
  for( i in 1:replicates) {
    y[i,]<-int+
      rnorm(1,0, sqrt(var_random_intercept))+
      slope*age+
      slope2*(age^2)+
      slope3*(age^3)
  }
  return(exp(colMeans(y))/(1+exp(colMeans(y))))
}

example_pred<-data.frame(
  "age"=c(2:38), 
  "fit1"=example(int=-2.267e+00, slope=6.150e-02, slope2 = 3.296e-03, slope3=-1.487e-04,  var_random_intercept = 0.3068, maxage = 38, minage=2, replicates = 1000000),
 "fit2"=example2(int=-2.267e+00 , slope=6.150e-02 , slope2 = 3.296e-03 , slope3=-1.487e-04,  var_random_intercept = 0.3068 , maxage = 38, minage=2, replicates = 1000000))


ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=example_pred, aes(x=age, y=fit1))+
  geom_line(data=example_pred, aes(x=age, y=fit2))


Any intel on the mathematical side of this would be greatly appreciated. If the outcomes are so different, which method should I use? The outcome from example is too high, the outcome from example2 (and from predict(scale="response")) is too low, is there a method that would get me values in between?

I’m wondering if is because of your failure to use poly rather than using I(.)^n?

Honestly, before your comment I did not know people preferred poly() to I()... Using poly() does improve my model, which is great! However, predict(type="response", re.form=NA) still yields values that are too low. Because of the complexty of the poly() function, I cannot manually predict my model fit anymore (I have tried a lot, but it kinda goes over my head). Unless I use poly(raw=TRUE), but as far as I understand then I lose all of the benefits of orthogonal polynomials and basically get the same model I would get with I()...
Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the poly direction! :)

If your probabilities are very small there is a bias built into the back-transformation. See e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#bias-adj

@Sofie. The “people” that prefer poly are statisticians.
